# Block commenting in Ruby

Tags: ruby, comments, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor, block-comments

Does Ruby have block comments?

If not, is there an efficient way of inserting `#` in front of a block of highlighted code in TextMate?

Comment: In Emacs, you can press `Meta-;` to comment / uncomment a selected region.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-Line Comments in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989762/multi-line-comments-in-ruby)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You can do

```
=begin
  [Multi line comment]
=end
```

`=begin` and `=end` must be at the beginning of the line (not indented at all).

[Source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#embed_doc)

Also, in TextMate you can press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to toggle regular comments on a highlighted block of code.

[Source](http://v1.garrettdimon.com/archives/trick-your-textmate-the-series)

Comment: One thing to note is that you must have the "Source" bundle enabled for the CMD + / shortcut to work. I had disabled it at some point in the past during an overzealous bundle purging rage and couldn't figure out why my Mac kept beeping at me whenever I tried using the comment shortcut.

Comment: Could be worth mentioning that Command + / also block comments in Sublime Text too

Comment: it goes wrong if there is some <% %> open tags in the block of commented code. Maybe there is any other way to do this?

Comment: Even better, they must be the only thing in their line. If you write something after "=begin" you get "syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end"

Answer (score 23):

Ruby has documentation comments - they look like this:

```
=begin
...
=end
```

Not perfect but they get the job done in a pinch.

[Edit] It is important to note that `=begin` and `=end` must be at the beginning of their respective lines.

Answer (score 2):

In TextMate, you can alt-drag vertically to select a column of text. This will duplicate the insertion point across all the lines you select, so you can insert or delete multiple `#`s at once.

UPDATE: Also in TextMate, assuming you have the right language selected, Cmd + / will toggle commenting every line in a selection regardless of language.

Comment: Yeah. Notepad++ lets you do this by holding alt as well (e.g. alt-shift-up arrow several times); UltraEdit and other editors have "column mode" as well.

Answer (score 0):

In TextMate 2 you can ⌘/ to comment out the current line or selected lines.