# Multi-line comments leads to unexpected tIDENTIFIER

Tags: ruby, comments

I am trying to add a few `>>> DocStrings`. Here is a piece of my code:

```
def service_destroy(service)

    =begin
        service_check(service) retun 0 || 1
        1 if service up and running
        0 otherwise
    =end

    ...
```

According to [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#comment) and other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989762/multi-line-comments-in-ruby), it must be ignored, but I have a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '='
    =begin
     ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start and end of multiline comments must be placed at the beginning of a line.