# How to comment Multiple lines in rails 5 controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to **comment multiple lines in Rails 5 controller**, I have searched the web and found the following solution: "=begin"

```
=begin (Multiple lines)
      respond_to do |format|
       if @person.update_attributes(params[:person])
        flash[:notice] = 'Person was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@person) }
        format.xml { head :ok }
       else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml { render :xml => @person.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
       end
      end
=end
```

But it gives this error:

> syntax error, unexpected '=' =begin

I am using Rails 5.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby multi line comments only work when there is no whitespace between the start of the line and the `=begin` (the same applies to the `=end`). Make sure the line starts with `=begin`:

This works:

```
=begin
  foo
  bar
=end
```

This won't work:

```
  =begin
    foo
    bar
  =end
```

Answer (score 2):

`=begin` and `=end` must not have any spaces before them

```
=begin
  code 
  I 
  want
  to 
  comment
=end
```

This is similar as commenting each line with `#`

```
# code 
# I 
# want
# to 
# comment
```

Answer (score 1):

=begin and =end should be at same level of indentation of class. Like below

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
=begin
=end
end
```

Comment: This is not quite correct. `=` of the comment token has to be the first symbol on the line, regardless whether this happens within a code of a class or not.

Comment: i agree with Nic Nilov, although Sven Koschnicke explained it better

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, multiline comment syntax in Ruby, although exists, is barely used. Some editors and syntax highlighters do not even recognize it. Your best bet is to use `#` on each commented line.

Additional benefit of using `#` is  the option of nesting the comments, something not possible with `=begin ... =end` syntax.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @person.update_attributes(params[:person])
    #  top level commented block
    #  flash[:notice] = 'Person was successfully updated.'
    #  # second level commented block
    #  # format.html { redirect_to(@person) }
    #  # format.xml { head :ok }
    # ...
  end
end
```

Your IDE should have no issues commenting/uncommenting a single comment level at a time.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989762/multi-line-comments-in-ruby) for the discussion.

Comment: hmm, but if we deal with a huge code then commenting each line would not be a good idea, a lot of time will be wasted

Comment: You should use your IDE's tools instead of manually typing every symbol. Multiline comment shortcuts are available basically everywhere.